# Use TFS Release Management with multplie Team Projects

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, ms-release-management

We are using TFS on premise, version 2015 update 3. We are using multiple team projects. Some Team Projects are used for applications (source control and builds), other team projects (with multple teams in it) are used for work item tracking. Teams can work on different applications.

Now we are looking into the Release functionality. Preferably we would like to use 1 team project to keep track of all the releases, so we get an overview of all releases in our organisation. But I can't figure out how to achieve this.

Is there a way to define release definitions linked to builds from an other Team Project? [Here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/author-release-definition/understanding-artifacts#link-artifacts) Microsoft says: "No additional setup is required when deploying Team Build artifacts published within the same team project." So I guess it should be possible to do an additional setup, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: You need to rethink how you are setup, This is not how TFS is supposed to be used. A single team project should contain all of the code, work items, build and releases for a single project/codebase/TP. At some level I believe you can set a build def in one TP to watch the folders from another but it would never be able to update work items from a third team project and you are taking a risk that permissions will not flow correctly between them all.

Comment: There were some reasons for this structure. Mainly because of legacy all the way from TFS 2005. Another reason is because the number of applications and build definitions. As a developer you don't want to scroll down searching your build definition in a long list. But I guess I should rethink our setup again...

Comment: Regarding builds, you should look at moving to the new Build system (build vNext) in TFS 2015. It much nicer than the xaml based system in older versions of TFS. It also has folders (finally) so you can organize your builds sensibly.

Answer (score 1):

We also have many team projects
We are using TFS 2015 CU2 but I do not think there are to many differences between the two versions.

The artifact link are for team builds within the same team project. I do think there is a way you can link to builds outside to other team projects.

In your one team project you could create all your CI builds there (in the build defintion mappings would can map to any source control path you want you simply have to cut in the path.)

If you still using your XAML build definitions; you could use the TFS Communinity build manager add-in for VS 2013 and clone the build defnition to you new team project.

So there is not easy way currently. We have chosen to release from every team project. The release overview is nice but we chose that it was not worth the effort. Maybe in the next release we will revise.

Comment: The biggest difference (for us) is the Release functionality integrated in TFS (we just came from TFS2015). In our current version we use the client/server version of MRM. In that version you still have an overview of all releases, even if the source code and builds are in different Team Projects.

Comment: Your suggestion of creating all builds in one team project is what we are investigating now. With all the other comments, it is clear to me that we should rethink our setup.

Comment: I would expect these team project limits to disappear in the upcoming release. I did not find anything in user voice https://visualstudio.uservoice.com. But would expect that what was possible in the previous version will eventually show up in the new version.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't separate aspects of your project (builds, code, releases, work items, etc) into different team projects. You lose all tracability if you do that, as you're seeing.

You can manage your application portfolio within a single team project with the appropriate use of Teams, but discussion of exactly how to achieve that is going to be very specific to your organization and thus is too broad to discuss on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I agree. We do want to manage our complete portfolio in a single Team Project, but that wasn't my goal to discuss with this question.